# Spotify API token

Tags: reactjs, token, spotify, fetch-api

I need to take some data from the spotify API, but I can not overcome this error:

```
error:{status: 401, message: "No token provided"}
```

I understand why this happens, but what I tried so far doesn´t work.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node'
import styles from './artist.css'




const Spotify = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const spotifyApi = new Spotify({
  clientId: '***************',
  clientSecret: '*************'
});


class Artist extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?        
 query=band&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20`, spotifyApi)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(artist => {
        console.log(artist)
      })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <h1> Hello World </h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of the module you are using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node) for getting/using a Spotify token?